# Prevent Default Page Format From Appearing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, formatting, style.css

I have several Sharepoint 2013 pages to which I've applied .css styles.  But whenever the pages load, the default format flashes on the screen before my .css is applied.  Does anyone have a script that would hide the default format completely - or prevent it from loading first?

Comment: SharePoint defines the order that the different style-sheets to load first in the MasterPage. https://thomasdaly.net/2012/05/02/sharepoint-cssregistration-or-link/

Comment: Where have you added the CSS for these pages?

Comment: The .css is on the pages - stored in content editor web part.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will load the default format and then load custom CSS stype.

Then you could add “!important” after the CSS code like the demo below.

```
<style>
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='multiplelinename']
{
width : 1000px !important;
}
</style>
```

The phenomenon that you will see the default format in the page before the custom CSS code when page loads, it only happens under the slow network speed.